# Message: imagecreatefrompng(): SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, image-processing, php-gd

I am getting the errors below:

> Message: imagecreatefrompng(): SSL operation failed with code 1

---

> Message: imagecreatefrompng(): Failed to enable crypto

when I run this code using PHP GD.

```
function image_test() {
    $im = imagecreatefrompng(base_url()."assets/developed/images/center-poster-bg-transparent.png");
    imagepng($im, APPPATH."../TESTIMAGE.png");
}
```

Can anybody help me out with why this is happening?

Comment: I'm making a lot of assumptions, but... You are probably trying to open an image from a `https` URL. That URL is probably using a self-signed certificate. In that case the OpenSSL extension in PHP won't be able to verify the certificate and fails.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you using codeigniter framework.
I have the same problem earlier.
And my solution is using the codeigniter parameter FCPATH.

Your code:

```
function image_test() {
    $im = imagecreatefrompng(base_url()."assets/developed/images/center-poster-bg-transparent.png");
    imagepng($im, APPPATH."../TESTIMAGE.png");
}
```

have to modify to

```
function image_test() {
    $im = imagecreatefrompng( FCPATH."assets/developed/images/center-poster-bg-transparent.png" );
    imagepng($im, APPPATH."../TESTIMAGE.png");
}
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Wow this was the issue I faced. It works. Thanks for this.